# Implementing JoinWithAnd method

Tags: java, strings, reinventing-the-wheel

> ## Objective
>
> Write a function `JoinWithAnd` in Java with the following signature:
>
> ```
> String JoinWithAnd(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e)
> ```
>
> So that:
>
> 1. If no input is provided, it returns an empty string
> 2. If any one input is provided, it returns the string as it is
> 3. If more than one inputs are provided, it combines all strings with AND in between and returns
>
> The input/output looks something like this:
>
> ```
>  -----------------------------------------------------------
> |Function Call                             |Returns         |
>  -----------------------------------------------------------
> |JoinWithAnd(null, null, null, null, null);|“”              |
> |JoinWithAnd(“A”, null, null, null, null); |“A”             |
> |JoinWithAnd(null, null, “C”, null, null); |“C”             | 
> |JoinWithAnd(“A”, “B”, null, null, null);  |“A AND B”       |
> |JoinWithAnd(“A”, null, “C”, “D”, null);   |“A AND C AND D” |
>  -----------------------------------------------------------
> ```
>
> ### Constraints
>
> - DO NOT change the method signature
> - DO NOT use arrays
> - DO NOT use `StringBuffer` or any other type of optimized `String` variants
> - DO NOT use Java Collection

The closest I could get is:

```
public class JoinWithAnd {

    private final String infix = " AND ";
    private final String regex = "( AND null)+";

    private String compute(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {
        return (a + infix + b + infix + c + infix + d + infix + e).replaceAll(regex, "");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JoinWithAnd oj = new JoinWithAnd();
        System.out.println(oj.compute("P", null, "R", "S", null));
    }

}
```

But this doesn't seem to be sufficient since it uses `replaceAll`.

Could anyone please suggest in what other ways this problem could be solved keeping all the constraints in mind?

Comment: Your code does not handle the case of a non null input string equals to "null".

Comment: You're right! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

#### Regex

I think your `String.replaceAll(String, String)` is fine, as regular expressions don't fall afoul of any of the rules. :) Just watch out for [@Bastien Aracil](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151042/implementing-joinwithand-method#comment284422_151042)'s comment, that you will be removing literal `"null"` values.

With that said...

#### Break the rules...?

> DO NOT use arrays
>
> DO NOT use `StringBuffer` or any other type of optimized `String` variants

These are going to be nearly impossible to conform, since a `String` is fundamentally a `char` array, *and* even a simple `"a" + "b"` uses an underlying `StringBuilder` for the concatenation. If one can partially 'hand-wave' the implicit `StringBuilder` away when using the `+` operator, I suppose one can also do a smaller 'hand-wave' of the implicit `char` array modification with [`String.concat(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat-java.lang.String-):

```
private static String join(String first, String second) {
    if (first == null || first.isEmpty()) {
        return second == null ? "" : second;
    }
    return second == null ? first : first.concat(" AND ").concat(second);
}
```

What we do here is to codify our logic as such:

1. If the `first` string is either `null` or empty, we either return `second` or an empty one.
2. Afterwards, if the `second` string is `null`, we return `first`, i.e. no concatenation done, or actually perform the concatenation with `" AND "`.

We then just need to 'recursively' call this with the five arguments, and a `null` or `""` as a 'starter' with `a`:

```
private static String joinWithAnd(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {
    return join(join(join(join(join(null, a), b), c), d), e);
}
```

#### Java 8

Going further, we can just rely on *streams* (not *collections*) and [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) (technically not a `String` 'variant', whatever that means) to get the same output:

```
private static String joinWithAnd(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {
    return Stream.of(a, b, c, d, e)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" AND "));
}
```

And, if one is being *extra* pedantic with the question's language, we can replace `Stream.of(T...)`, technically an array, with multiple `Stream.concat(Stream, Stream)` calls:

```
// return Stream.of(a, b, c, d, e)
return Stream.concat(Stream.concat(Stream.concat(Stream.concat(
                Stream.of(a), Stream.of(b)), Stream.of(c)), Stream.of(d)), Stream.of(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to comply with a constraint of not using any String API would be by building output using ternary operator as shown below:

```
public class JoinWithAnd {

    private final String infix = " AND ";

    private String compute(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {
        return (((a != null) ? a : "") + ((b != null) ? infix + b : "") + ((c != null) ? infix + c : "")
                + ((d != null) ? infix + d : "") + ((e != null) ? infix + e : ""));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JoinWithAnd oj = new JoinWithAnd();
        System.out.println(oj.compute("P", null, "R", "S", null));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursivity: handle the special case where `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` are `null`, then try to reach this case by calling again the method.

```
public static final String DELIMITER = " AND ";

public static String joinWithAnd(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e) {
    if (b==null && c==null && d == null && e == null) {
        return a==null?"":a;
    }
    //recurse to reach the special case above
    //by using (b,c,d,e,null) arguments
    final String end = joinWithAnd(b,c,d,e,null);
    //complete the join with the left out 'a' argument
    return a==null?end:a+DELIMITER+end;
}
```